# HTTPService not properly JSON-encoding nested objects on send()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, actionscript-3, httpservice

i am creating an object like this:

```
var myObj:Object = new Object();
myObj["someProperty"] = {
   anotherProperty: "someValue",
   whateverProperty: "anotherValue"
}
```

now i want to send it to a web server (rails):

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url = "http://server.com/some/path/entry.json";
service.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
service.send( myObj );
```

the problem is that the server receives the json like this:

```
{"someProperty"=>"[object Object]"}
```

is this a problem with HTTPService? should i use the good old loader/urlrequest and serialize myself? by the way, serializing and then passing the string doesn't work, webserver receives empty request as GET.

but i kinda want to use the httpservice class though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SerializationFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/SerializationFilter.html) with your HTTPService to correctly serialize the data you pass as an object to `HTTPService.send()`.

The way in which this works is to create a custom SerializationFilter to perform the specific action required.  In your case, you want to convert the outgoing body Object to a JSON format String.  To do this you should override the `serializeBody` method:

```
package
{
    import mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation;
    import mx.rpc.http.SerializationFilter;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

    public class JSONSerializationFilter extends SerializationFilter
    {
        override public function serializeBody(operation:AbstractOperation, obj:Object):Object
        {
            return JSON.encode(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

You can assign an instance of this filter to your HTTPService before calling `send()`:

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url = "http://server.com/some/path/entry.json";
service.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
//add the serialization filter
service.serializationFilter = new JSONSerializationFilter();
service.send( myObj );
```

Once assigned, this filter will be invoked for all the operations this HTTPService instance performs.  You can also add more override methods to your custom filter to handle the incoming response.

Comment: i am using those classes on numerous occasions but httpservice does not take a string for the send() method. so it deems the parameters to be empty, changes the request type to GET and the server gets nothing. i just want to basically know if someone can confirm that httpservice is unable to encode nested objects to json.

Comment: @DasAntonym - sorry, here is a better answer. I've not tested it for your useage, but hopefully it'll set you on the right track.

Comment: thanks shane, that is definitely a good advice to look into those serialization filters. only problem now is that i now get the same behaviour like when i just pass JSON.encode(obj) to the send() method. the request becomes a GET-request and the server receives nothing. just like when passing nothing to the send() method.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [Mike Chamber's JSON serialization library](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) for encoding / decoding (serializing) data in JSON.

Basically, you need to convert your object into a JSON representation. The [JSONEncoder class](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONEncoder.as) is useful for this.

There's a [useful (old but still very relevant for using HTTPService + JSON) tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-php-json-mysql-advanced-updating) that goes through it, but essentially you should call JSON.encode() on what your "someProperty" value is.

i.e.:

```
var dataString:String = JSON.encode(dataValue);
dataString = escape(dataString);
myObj["someProperty"] = dataString;
```

Comment: this is actually something i wanted to avoid. in the tutorial they decode the value of the property (which is a string type attached to an object on submission) manually. i want a proper json-encoded nested object, because i do not want to implement a non-standard way to read the data in rails.